# Prove that $\frac1{x}-x$ is multiplicatively subadditive in $(0, 1)$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

If
$f(x) = \dfrac1{x}-x$,
prove that
$f(x)$ is *multiplicatively subadditive* in
$(0, 1)$,
that is,

if $a, b \in (0, 1)$,
then
$f(a)+f(b) < f(ab)$.

Comment: Hint: Write it out! $$ \dfrac {1}{a} - a + \dfrac {1}{b} - b $$ vs. $$ \dfrac {1}{ab} - ab. $$ Also, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(ab) - f(a) - f(b)$ and use $1 - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show one expression is larger than another, it is often helpful to consider the difference:

$$\begin{align}
f(ab) - f(a) - f(b) &= \frac{1}{ab} - \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} + a + b - ab\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{ab} - \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} + 1\right) - \left(1 - a - b + ab\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{a} - 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{b} - 1\right) - (1-a)(1-b)\\
&= \frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{ab} - (1-a)(1-b)\\
&= (1-a)(1-b)\left(\frac{1}{ab} - 1\right)\\
&> 0.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we take $f(a)$ as $a$ approaches $0$. Then $f(a)$ approaches infinity. If we take $f(b)$ approaching $1$, then $f(b)$ approaches $0$. If we take $f(ab)$ with the same conditions, then ab should approach $0$ - but it is less than $f(a)$, which is important to note, because that means $f(ab)$ approaches infinity faster than $f(a)$ does.

Comment: M.A.: The question is not about limits, but just about proving an inequality. This doesn't answer the question, really.

Comment: Reconsider your comment. I'm at a loss at how this does not help.

Comment: What you want to prove is that $f(a)+f(b)<f(ab)$ for $0<a,b<1$. The above has nothing to do with that. Both $a$ and $b$ are fixed numbers in $(0,1)$.

Comment: My idea was that if we take a, b as close as we can to the boundary (0, 1), then it is seen that ab < a. This is because a*b < a*1. Thus, f(a) < f(ab).

I hope that helps, I really tried; I do not know what to do about the f(b) though.

Comment: But we have to prove this for *any* $a,b$, and we have to prove $f(a)+f(b)<f(ab)$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10151/discussion-between-mathapprentice-and-peter-tamaroff)